# Deserializing XML File attributes

Tags: c#, .net-core, xml-parsing

I'm trying to deserialize the following xml file:

```
   <item>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>https://blog.sitename.com/link</link>         <comments>https://blog.sitename.com/link/#respond</comments>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[name]]></dc:creator>
    <pubDate>Thu, 30 Apr 2020 18:59:06 +0000</pubDate>
<description><p>description...</p><p> continue</p></description>
    <category><![CDATA[General News]]></category>
    <media:content url="https://blog.gotproperty.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/image.jpg" medium="image" />
    </item>
```

My class is the following

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
      public class item
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string link { get; set; }
            public string comments{ get; set; }

            [XmlElement("media:content")]
            public Image Image { get; set; }

            public string description { get; set; }
            public string shortDescription
            {
                get
                {
                    var decodeHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(description);

                    var result = decodeHtml.Substring(decodeHtml.IndexOf('>') +1, decodeHtml.IndexOf("</") - decodeHtml.IndexOf('>') -1);

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        public class Image
        {
            [XmlAttribute("url")]
            public string url { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("medium")]
            public string medium { get; set; }

        }
```

Everything is parsing except for the "media:content" element which uses the Image class where the url and medium is defined as XmlAttributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<media:content>` is not an xml element name; that is `<content>`, but in the namespace by whatever you have an alias `xmlns:media` referring to; so if you have `xmlns:media="http://foo/bar"`, then this is:

```cs
[XmlElement("content", Namespace = "http://foo/bar")]
public Image Image { get; set; }
```

To be explicit: if you have `xmlns:media="http://foo/bar"`, then: `<media:content>` is similar to `<content xmlns="http://foo/bar">`, except that the namespace `"http://foo/bar"` is not inherited by child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Update on Marc Gravell's Answer.

Sorry didn't realize the Xml header is needed so I only posted a snipped of the Xml file.

Xml header

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
        xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
        xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    >
```

Class Update

```
[XmlElement("content", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
public Image Image { get; set; }
```